# Is it appropriate to write mixed capped abbreviations and acronyms in all caps for headers, etc?

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, acronyms, formatting

When using an abbreviation or acronym that has a mix of lowercase and capital letters, such as mmWave or dBm, in a heading or line that is formatted in all caps, is it appropriate to use all caps - or should you leave the mixed caps?

Comment: 1n what medium? If online, what software are you using? What style guide are you following, that mandates capitals? I suggest using caps and small caps. Provided that you have small caps available and may use them.

Comment: dB·m is a symbol, not an abbreviation, and in that distinction lies your answer. (Dot or space symbol strings. [NIST 811](https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-chapter-6-rules-and-style-conventions-printing-and-using)

Comment: See also [NIST 811 7.8](https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-chapter-7-rules-and-style-conventions-expressing-values#76note3), which would likely apply to headings.

Comment: I agree with the answers regarding symbols for SI units and such, but with stylised mixed-case or lower-case brand names, band names, etc, it's different, and common to put them into another, more normal form. (See e.g. [this discussion](https://www.writing-skills.com/how-to-write-brand-names))

Comment: mixed capital letters. short form: caps. In these business thingies, keep what they use.

Comment: Bank of America, for example, uses the stylized acronym BoA even in capitalized headers. If you're working for a client, you should probably ask for a style guide.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to use mixed cases especially if the abbreviation or acronym had a special meaning.  Decibel is written as dBa.  Reading that I immediately know you are speaking of sound however changing the case can often distort or confuse the reader.

Answer (score 0):

> is it appropriate to use all caps - or should you leave the mixed caps?

Leave the mixed capitals!

From the [IEEE website](https://www.ewh.ieee.org/soc/ias/pub-dept/abbreviation.pdf) APPENDIX VII Recommended Unit Symbols, SI Prefixes, and Abbreviations:

**M** = mega, e.g. 20MW = twenty million Watts,

whereas

**m** = milli e.g. 20mW = twenty milliwatts = 0.02 Watts